# How can I tell who is marked by the Will of the Gods?

Tags: hand-of-fate

I've gotten the blessing "Will of the Gods" on a couple runs, but I've never been able to tell which enemy was marked for killing first.

On those runs I've also had elemental weapons that add other visual effects to enemies (like Armour of Cold). Would those interfere with the Will of the Gods effect?

Regardless, what indicator is there on enemies to let me know they are marked to die first?